# Where does StreamWriter store data stream if using or dispose is not used?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stream, writer

I used StreamWriter in my code without using or dispose to create a csv file. It worked fine at first but it always generated same file which it generated the first time I ran my code. Even if I changed Data selection, it was same file. Then I copied my dll on a different environment, only dll no other file was changed and it still generated the same file, with exact same data from previous environment. It seems that my code is buffering the data from first run, but where?? By even changing hosting environment, why it's the buffer didn't change?

Comment: it's difficult to help without code

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `StreamWriter` it either accepts a `Stream` to write to or creates its own.  The `Stream` instance uses buffering to hold data that is being written and needs to be flushed.  This is done when you `Dispose` the `Stream` or the `StreamWriter` but is likely to be skipped if you let the garbage collector finalize either.

Which is why you should **always** dispose your streams when you're done with them, and why you *should* call `Flush` on a `Stream` when you've finished writing data to it that you don't want to lose.  An unhandled exception in your code that bypasses your `Dispose` can cause you to lose data.

Personally I prefer to dispose of the `Stream` as soon as possible.  Unless you're constantly writing hundreds of times a second it doesn't cost much to re-open a file to append some more data to it later.